# OpenGL glDrawArrays for GL_POINTS and GL_LINES are on different pixels for same points

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, glfw

Using the normalized [-1,1] points `A = (0.5, 0.5)`, `B = (0.5, -0.5)`, `C = (-0.5, -0.5)`, and `D = (-0.5, 0.5)`, I'm drawing these points as pixels with `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 4)`. I found that when I also call `glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 4)` to draw the 2 lines `AB` and `CD` there's a 1 pixel difference in the x-direction between the points and the endpoints of the 2 lines. Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image: img]

I was also able to get this problem to go away if I changed the window size from 800x600 to 850x600. I'm thinking this might have to do with odd or even size window width, but I'm not sure. In my code, you can comment out `#define SHOW_PROBLEM` to change the window size where the problem doesn't occur. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my complete code for reference:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow * window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow * window);

#define SHOW_PROBLEM
#ifdef SHOW_PROBLEM

// These dimensions show the problem
#define WINDOW_WIDTH 800
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 600

#else

// These dimensions DO NOT show the problem
#define WINDOW_WIDTH 850
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 600

#endif

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow * window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "OpenGLDemo", nullptr, nullptr);

    if (!window)
    {
        std::cout << std::unitbuf
                  << "[ERROR] " << __FILE__ << ':' << __LINE__ << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
                  << "\n[ERROR] " << "Failed to create GLFW window!"
                  << std::nounitbuf << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        std::abort();
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader(reinterpret_cast<GLADloadproc>(glfwGetProcAddress)))
    {
        std::cout << std::unitbuf
                  << "[ERROR] " << __FILE__ << ':' << __LINE__ << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
                  << "\n[ERROR] " << "Failed to initialize GLAD!"
                  << std::nounitbuf << std::endl;

        std::abort();
    }

    // vertex shader
    const char * vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
                                      "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
                                      "void main()\n"
                                      "{\n"
                                      " gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
                                      "}\0";

    unsigned int vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, nullptr, infoLog);

        std::cout << std::unitbuf
                  << "[ERROR] " << __FILE__ << ':' << __LINE__ << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
                  << "\n[ERROR] " << "Vertex shader compilation failed!"
                  << "\n[ERROR] " << infoLog
                  << std::nounitbuf << std::endl;

        std::abort();
    }

    // fragment shader
    const char * fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
                                        "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
                                        "void main()\n"
                                        "{\n"
                                        "    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
                                        "}\0";

    unsigned int fragmentShader;
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, nullptr, infoLog);

        std::cout << std::unitbuf
                  << "[ERROR] " << __FILE__ << ':' << __LINE__ << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
                  << "\n[ERROR] " << "Fragment shader compilation failed!"
                  << "\n[ERROR] " << infoLog
                  << std::nounitbuf << std::endl;

        std::abort();
    }

    unsigned int shaderProgram;
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, nullptr, infoLog);

        std::cout << std::unitbuf
                  << "[ERROR] " << __FILE__ << ':' << __LINE__ << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
                  << "\n[ERROR] " << "Shader program linking failed!"
                  << "\n[ERROR] " << infoLog
                  << std::nounitbuf << std::endl;

        std::abort();
    }

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    float vertices[] = {
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,    // top right
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom left
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f    // top left
    };


    unsigned int VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    unsigned int VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), reinterpret_cast<void *>(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // 6. render loop

    glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        processInput(window);

        // background
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 4);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 4);

        // check and call events and swap the buffers
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    // de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow * window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}


void processInput(GLFWwindow * window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    }
}
```

This may also be useful:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: 1) Floating point is not exact.  2) Also, the line A-B will be different than the line B-A.

Comment: Though floating point is not exact, the values he used for coords there are. I think the 2) of your comment is the relevant part :)

Comment: @stark Why would A-B not be the same as B-A?

Comment: Doesn't reproduce on nvidia GTX 750 Ti, but does on Mesa/Intel UHD Graphics 620. I suspect a bug in Mesa.

Comment: @Ruslan You tested both Mesa/Intel UHD Graphics 620 and nvidia GTX 750 Ti?

Comment: Yes. Different machines though, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: Your coordinates are on pixel boundaries, so some inaccuracy is to be expected. Try to align them to pixel centers.

Comment: The results you get is well within what the GL spec allows. Floating-point precision is also no issue here - the GPU rasterizer works with fixed point, and any floating point issues which could occur when transforming this to window space are oders of magnitude smaller, the vertices are exactly on the pixel boundaries in clip space, and they will end up exactly on pixel boundaries in the GPUs fixed pointer rasterizer format. And what happens from there is completely up to the implementation.

Answer (score -1):

for `GL_LINES` the rasterizer would have to interpolate across two vertices, and with any other interpolated values from the vertex to fragment shaders, you should not rely on some kind of equality between hardcoded values and the interpolated. The resizing of windows tells you that the difference is just due to this interpolation/float error. If you goal is to color the vertices, try adding logic in your shader to check whether the current pixel fragment is very  close to the 2 vertices it's interpolated from and color accordingly.